# UFT error clicking on Link gives me an error

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Here is my script

```
systemutil.Run "www.google.com"
Browser("name:=.*").Page("title:=.*").link("name:=Gmail").Click
```

I have tried with different properties and their values but I still get the same error

The error I am getting is...

> Cannot identify the object "[ Link ]" (of class Link). Verify that this object's properties match an object currently displayed in your application.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Browser("name:=.*").Sync` to allow the page to complete loading before you try to click the link?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that may be going on here.

1. AFAIK the `name` property looks at the HTML `name` property, you're probably looking for the link according to the `textContent` (known in UFT as `innnertext`).
2. In descriptive programming in UFT the value is treated as a regular expression that is [anchored on both sides](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2018/11/05/regular-expressions-in-uft/).

Try the following:

```
Browser("name:=.*").Page("title:=.*").link("innertext:=.*Gmail.*").Click
```

In any case you should use UFT's [Object Spy](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Spy.htm) in order to see what the object's actual property values are.